# Why I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Delete is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick IF IS already defined?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm just creating a onclick function called `Delete()` but I don't know why, I get `Detele()` is not defined, but of it is.

My onClick function is in my button:

```
$data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $field)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>";
```

And my function:

```
function Delete(id, tableName, field){
    //$.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tabla + "&nombre_campo=" + campo + "&id=" + id, function(data){
    $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", {
        action: "deleteRegistro",
        id: id,
        tableName: tableName,
        field: field
        }, function (data, status) {

        if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro?") == true) {
            if (status === 'error') {
                console.log("Not deleted"); // For debugging purpose
            } else if (status === 'success') {
                console.log("Deleted successfully");                                
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This is my full code:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
include_once(DIR_PLUGINS.'/alexcrudgenerator/main.php');

    $test = new GenerateCrud($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
    
    if ($_GET['action']){
        print_a($_GET['action']);
    }

    switch($_POST['action']){
        
        case 'datosTabla': // OK.
            
            //print_r($_POST['action']);
            $res = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
            echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            
            break;
        
        case 'deleteRegistro':
            
            $id = $_POST['id']; // Quiero obtener estas variables que he enviado desde la función Delete();
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName']; // Quiero obtener estas variables que he enviado desde la función Delete();
            $field = $_POST['field']; // Quiero obtener estas variables que he enviado desde la función Delete();
            
            break;
            
        case 'showtable': // OK.

            $res = getEntireTable($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
            
            $field = json_decode($_POST['tableFields'],1)[0];
            //print_r($tableName);
            //print_r('<br>');
            //print_r($campo);
            
            foreach ($res as $data){                
                $data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $field)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>"; 
                $resultados['data'][] = $data;
            }           
            
            $resultados = json_encode($resultados); // 7 PROPIEDADES
            
            foreach(json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsDB){
                $fields[] = array('data'=>$columnsDB);
            }

            $fields[]['data'] = 'acción';
            $fields = json_encode($fields);
            
?>
            <head>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            
            <div class="container caja">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div>
                            <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed hover" style="width:100%" >
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            foreach (json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsTH){
                                                 echo '<th>' . strtoupper($columnsTH) . '</th>';
                                            }
                                            echo '<th>ACCIÓN</th>';
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                    
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var datos= <?=$resultados?>;
                    var dynamicColumns = <?=$fields?>;
                    datos = JSON.stringify(datos);
                    
                    $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
                        "language": {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "scrollX": true,

                        "ajax":{
                            "url": '<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/',
                            "method": 'POST',
                            "data":{action: "datosTabla", datos: datos}
                        },

                        "columns": dynamicColumns
                    });

                    function Delete(id, tableName, field){
                        //$.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tabla + "&nombre_campo=" + campo + "&id=" + id, function(data){
                        $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", {
                            action: "deleteRegistro",
                            id: id,
                            tableName: tableName,
                            field: field
                            }, function (data, status) {
        
                            if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro?") == true) {
                                if (status === 'error') {
                                    console.log("Not deleted"); // For debugging purpose
                                } else if (status === 'success') {
                                    console.log("Deleted successfully");                                
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
            </script>
<?php
        break;      
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**
I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: users_test is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`, where `users_test` is the value of my `$tableName` and `tableName`.

Comment: It's not in scope. Try defining it with `window.Delete = function(...args) ...whatever your code is.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you get that error because the Delete() function is defined inside the

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Every function you write there is local and can only be called from the document.ready function

- So, this would not work

```js
Delete();     

$(document).ready(function() {
    function Delete(){             //function inside
        console.log("Erase");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- This should work

```js
Delete();    

function Delete(){           //function outside
    console.log("Erase");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now, I get as "undefined" the parameter `$tableName` and `tableName`. Why could it be?  I edit my code for you to see.

Comment: I´m not seeing something strange in the code. It seems to me that this `$_POST['tableName']` is returning undefined. You should inspect the code with chrome while running and look if the onClick function has valid parameters